# Blazor InputSelect binds to option text instead of Value

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I use Blazor serverside and I have this:

```
<InputSelect class="form-control" id="sYear" @bind-Value="@SelectedYear">
    <option value="" selected="@(SelectedYear == "")">Year</option>
    @foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(admin.GetYearOfGregorianDate(DateTime.Now) - 20, 21).Reverse())
    {
        <option value="@i" selected="@(SelectedYear == i.ToString())">@i.ToString()</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

As is seen, the value for the first option is empty and I expect when I choose the first option the bound value become empty string Not the string "Year" but the SelectedYear is set to "Year"!
What to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the selected tag?
Why would you want to use the selected-tag?
The value of SelectedYear is bind to the option-value by default.

```
<InputSelect class="form-control" id="sYear" @bind-Value="@SelectedYear">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    @foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(admin.GetYearOfGregorianDate(DateTime.Now) - 20, 21).Reverse())
    {
        <option value="@i">@i.ToString()</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```